# When hosting doesn't support !empty($value) what can i do?

Tags: php, arrays, string, wordpress

I made a website on my pc i use xampp and latest php version, website is made on WordPress and when i uploaded a website to user hosting i just realised they don't have latest php version, and asking for support they said not our problem, we don't want to break other sites just to make your working.

So what can i do. For some arrays i used !empty to check if string returns empty value and if it's not empty show the content.

This looks like this

```
if(!empty($current_meta['slides']) === true) {
get_slider( $current_meta['slides'] );
}
```

So this works on my pc but on client hosting it doesn't work i get an error

```
Can't use function return value in write context
```

When i test with print_r what's output it generates an error like this

```
 Illegal string offset 'slides'
```

When i do var_dump i get this

```
string(0) ""
```

So what can i do to fix the errors ?

i tried as i read on net some sugestions

```
if($current_meta['slides'] != '') {
vf_get_slider( $current_meta['slides'] );
}
```

But this generates errors on both my pc and online host.

Edit

I updated all my files as suggested by answer below now i have it like this

```
$slides_meta = $current_meta['slides'];
if(!empty($slides_meta)) {
    vf_get_slider( $current_meta['slides']);
}
```

And it works on server where i uploaded, but now errors started to show on my own pc.

I have php version 5.5.8 and user hosting is 5.3.22

Comment: You will be using PHP5.5 that supports expressions with `empty`.

Comment: I would honestly do that but i don't have control over who will buy what. That's why i have my own vps for my sites to be able to have control over things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP.net on empty:

```
empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to !isset($var) || $var == false.
```

So if you need an alternative to !empty, it would be

```
 !(!isset($var) || $var == false)
```

or

```
(isset($var) && $var != false)
```

That being said - empty is almost certainly supported by your host.  Only recently, however, has PHP started supporting expressions inside empty.  So if you have anything like

```
 if (!empty(trim($var))
```

You need to change it to something like:

```
 $var = trim($var);
 if (!empty($var))
```

Comment: How is this in any way relevant to the error message? The disparity between the error message and the given code clearly shows that the code has nothing to do with the error, and that we've probably been given the wrong code.

Comment: Also, `empty` has been around since PHP 4. Unless the host is still using PHP 3, this answer is useless.

Comment: You got that part about expressions right. So if i use $current_meta['slides'] it drops an error but if i set $slides = $current_meta['slides'] than if(!empty($slides)) the error is dropped. At least on first few codes i tested, ill check other variables i have to see if this will fix it.

Comment: I replaced every value as you suggested and now it works on user hosting, however now i get an errors now on my own pc. I have php 5.5.8 version and user hosting have php 5.3

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
if($current_meta['slides'] != '') {
     vf_get_slider( $current_meta['slides'] );
}
```

you had additional closing bracket in your code

Comment: that's just mistake in here, on site i don't have that, otherwise it would drop an error about closing bracket. Anyway i checked again if brackets are problem but that's not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem you should replace the following piece of code:

```
if(!empty($current_meta['slides']) === true) {
    get_slider( $current_meta['slides'] );
}
```

With this one:

```
if(!empty($current_meta['slides'])) {
    get_slider( $current_meta['slides'] );
}
```